# Create a new col in pandas with element of other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hel lo, I would need help.

I have a dataframe such as :

table:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Sign
Loc1    1   60  -
Loc2    10  90  +
Loc3    40  100 +
Loc4    20  40  -
```

and from this table I want to create a `Newcol` with elements in others columns such as :

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Sign    Newcol
Loc1    1   60  -   Loc1:1-60(-)
Loc2    10  90  +   Loc2:11-90(+)
Loc3    40  100 +   Loc3:41-100(+)
Loc4    20  40  -   Loc4:20-40(-)
```

I tried:

```
table["Newcol"]=table['Col1']+":"+str(table['Col2'])+"-"+str(table['Col3'])+"("+table['Sign']+")"
```

But how can I take into account the fact that when I have a `+` sign, I have to add `+1` to the `Col3` for the `Newcol` name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) for convert to strings and for add `1` compare by `+` and convert value to integer with [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
table["Newcol"] = (table['Col1']+":"+
                  (table['Col2'].add(table['Sign'].eq('+').astype(int))).astype(str)+"-"+
                  (table['Col3']).astype(str)+"("+
                   table['Sign']+")")
print (table)
   Col1  Col2  Col3 Sign          Newcol
0  Loc1     1    60    -    Loc1:1-60(-)
1  Loc2    10    90    +   Loc2:11-90(+)
2  Loc3    40   100    +  Loc3:41-100(+)
3  Loc4    20    40    -   Loc4:20-40(-)
```